# Storing output messages inside constants in PHP

Tags: php, constants, message

Will it downgrade performance significantly (or exhaust the server with http requests), or maybe ill advised, to do something like this

```
echo "<span>enter_username_message</span>";
```

and centralize this constant along with all output messages in one file, so that those could be changed without getting into the code:

```
define('enter_username_message','username please');
```

that way, if someone were viewing the website in its spanish version, I could simply direct php to require all those output-message constants from a spanish file.

```
define('enter_username_message','username por favor');
```

what do you think?

Comment: That seems like a good practice... don't see a huge problem there.

Comment: Yes i am also doing this way, its good for me.. keep it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just use gettext: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

It's designed for the kind of thing you're talking about.

**Edit**
Apparently PHP gettext isn't thread safe (ugh, I hate PHP), so perhaps look at something like Zent Translate with the gettext adapter, which is thread safe:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

My reason for suggesting using something gettext based is the various tools that are available for creating and editing gettext .po/.mo files, which make creating translations easier than just going through some text file and editing things.

Comment: quoting: "As a reminder, this is not thread-safe and will not work on typical windows/apache installs."

And it surely will introduce more overhead than the original poster idea.

Comment: Using the gettext "EXTENSION" is the only way to go in respect to performance IMO and from benchmarks

Comment: this won't have any effect on the # of http requests - still just 1 to load the page + 1 for each external resource. so from that standpoint there's no problem.

Comment: @jasondavis: what about the aforementioned lack of thread safety?